# Move a prvalue into function template uref argument or not?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, forwarding-reference, prvalue

my question is if it would make sense to std::move (or not) a prvalue into a catch-all function template which accordingly takes a universal reference T&& in its signature. Also I would like to know if copy-move elision/RVO is playing a role in this decision.

Question(s):
Will reference collapsing result in foo being called with T&& (rvalue reference) with or w/o std::move and does RVO have any effect on that (or that on RVO)?

```
template < typename T >
void foo(T&& arg)
{
    //Whatever..
}

A func()
{
    A m;
    return m;
}

// called anywhere you like
foo(std::move(func()));
```

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: Start by learning what `main()` returns... Anyway, this is a vague question or set of questions, and I can't believe that (A) it hasn't already been answered or (B) you couldn't write your own test for it.

Comment: I only wanted to emphasize a scope with the main function. The focus lies on the call and what exactly happens. Anyway, I correct it if that helps focusing on the question.

Comment: And yes, this is more of theoretical nature. I would like to know what is supposed to happen and therefore what to expect, not what my specific compiler is doing. This is purely research to me as I am not sure I understand the chain of events correctly. If you don‘t wanna help, that‘s fine. But maybe someone else is. And existing topics I found could not dissolve my doubts yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `move` has no effect whatsoever other than making the compiler, the optimizer, and the readers of your code do more pointless work.

Don't do it.